# Nginx not logging $remote_port when coming from cloudflare

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

We offen receive requests from police to provide the ip and port of visitors.

When the requests come via cloudflare(https), the $remote_port variable is empty, when I access the load balancer via it's ip the port is set correctly.

```
log_format  main  '[$time_local] - $http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_addr - p$remote_port - $status - $request_time - "$uri"';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFlare does not pass that information to you, so it is not surprising that you do not have it.

The only information CloudFlare provides is [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-). If the port is needed then police will have to get the IP from you and take the request to CloudFlare to get the port number.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but could not find anything official from cloudflare or anything at all while googling.